# How Do I Ask Google To Completely Delete An App From My Play Console

Tags: console, google-play-console

I would like for one of my apps in my play console to be deleted completely. It was recently rejected but before that I had unpublished it just two days after publishing it, when it was under review. So I don't want it to appear in my account anymore.

I uploaded and unpublished before it could go live.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delete it by yourself.

but you can contact support team after unpublishing your app and ask the to remove it, it will take sometime.

UPDATE: how to contact Google Play Support

from console press the help button an choose `Contact US`
[image]

Comment: I ask them using which of their emails?

Comment: @BwembyaMubanga I've updated my answer to show you how